# How to perform parity tranformation in a Lagrangian?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, parity

In this forum https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-to-check-if-lagrangian-is-parity-invariant.333562/ appears a discussion about the performing of the [parity transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(physics)) in the Dirac Lagrangian.

The OP's author (RedX) says that the partial derivative of this Lagrangian should change such as

$$\partial_\mu = (\partial_0, \nabla) \rightarrow \bar{\partial}_\mu = (\partial_0, -\nabla)$$

Meanwhile, another user, JavierR, holds that the partial derivative isn't transformed when testing parity in the Lagrangian. JavierR's method gives parity invariance to Dirac's Lagrangian while RedX's doesn't, but I don't understand why the derivative remains unchanged if we are checking invariance under parity in the whole Lagrangian, not the fields.

Amin, when you make a transformation like this one you have top apply it to the whole system (fields) and the equations, or am I wrong?

Comment: What is the definition of "parity" transformation here? You can do a transformation on spacetime and call it parity, or you can just let an operator interchange left- and right-handed fields and call it parity.

Comment: There is an edit with a link, but it is just changing the spatial coordinates: $\vec{r} \rightarrow -\vec{r}$