# Dirac Lagrangian not Parity Invariant?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices, parity

I am following the book 'Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model(2014)' by Matthew D. Schwartz, and I have some incertitude with regards to some subtleties that I have come across while reading Chapter 11.5, 'Parity' part.

Section 11.5.1 Starts from defining how the parity operation is acted on fields and operators each.
In Eq 11.6.2 it argues that in order for

> P : $A_{\mu}(\phi^{*}\partial_{\mu}\phi-\phi\partial_{\mu}\phi^{*})\rightarrow A_{\mu}(\phi^{*}\partial_{\mu}\phi-\phi\partial_{\mu}\phi^{*})$

to hold, $A_{\mu}$ should transform like a Lorentz 4 vector (not a pseudovector) $\partial_{\mu}$ , i.e.

> P : $A_{0}(t,\vec{x})\rightarrow A_{0}(t,-\vec{x})  \quad,\quad   A_{i}(t,\vec{x}) \rightarrow -A_{i}(t,-\vec{x})$

At least from my understanding, this statement implicitly means that the parity operation with their actions defined on our scalar and vector fields here should act on  $\partial_{\mu}$ as well, thereby cancelling the (-) signs appearing as extra sign factor attached only on spatial parts upon parity operation on the vector fields.

> P : $\partial_{0}\rightarrow \partial_{0} \quad , \quad \partial_{i}\rightarrow -\partial_{i}  $
> (My Presumption)

OK. All fine up to this point. But then I come across this line on the very next page, p.198.

> "... so that $\overline{\psi}\gamma_{\mu}\psi $ transforms exactly as a 4-vector and hence the Dirac Lagrangian is parity invariant.

This was the part that got me confused cause defining parity as above didn't seem to give invariance for the kinetic term appearing in the Dirac Lagrangian. $\mathcal{L}=\overline{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi+...$

First, note that the parity operation sends

> P :  $\overline{\psi}(t,\vec{x})\gamma_{\mu}\psi(t,\vec{x})\rightarrow \psi^{\dagger}(t,-\vec{x})\gamma_{0}\gamma_{0}\gamma_{\mu}\gamma_{0}\psi(t,-\vec{x})=\overline{\psi}(t,-\vec{x})\gamma_{\mu}^{\dagger}\psi(t,-\vec{x})$

But since $\gamma_{0}^{\dagger}=\gamma_{0}$ and $\gamma_{i}^{\dagger}=-\gamma_{i}$ in the Weyl representation, we have

> P :  $\overline{\psi}(t,\vec{x})\gamma_{0}\psi(t,\vec{x})\rightarrow \overline{\psi}(t,-\vec{x})\gamma_{0}\psi(t,-\vec{x})  \qquad and \qquad  \overline{\psi}(t,\vec{x})\gamma_{i}\psi(t,\vec{x})\rightarrow -\overline{\psi}(t,-\vec{x})\gamma_{i}\psi(t,-\vec{x})$

and thus our kinetic term in the Dirac Lagrangian behaves like

> P : $\overline{\psi}(t,\vec{x})\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi(t,\vec{x})\rightarrow \overline{\psi}(t,-\vec{x})\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi(t,-\vec{x})$

But this is a problem since this is not invariant in the action $ S= \int d^{4}x \mathcal{L}$ since upon $ \vec{x}\rightarrow -\vec{x}$ in the overall $d^{3}x$ integration for the i (spatial) part it behaves

> $\vec{x}\rightarrow -\vec{x}\quad  : \quad \overline{\psi}(t,-\vec{x})\gamma^{i}\partial_{i}\psi(t,-\vec{x})\quad \rightarrow \quad \overline{\psi}(t,\vec{x})\gamma^{i}(-\partial_{i})\psi(t,\vec{x})\neq \overline{\psi}(t,\vec{x})\gamma^{i}(\partial_{i})\psi(t,\vec{x})$

and hence the kinetic term is clearly not invariant upon integration over all $\vec{x}$ after $ \vec{x}\rightarrow -\vec{x}$ exchange! Instead there will be a flipped sign only for the spatial part when we do the $\int d^{4}x$ to evaluate the action.

What could be the problem here? Is it because the parity should only act on the fields so that there are no flipping of sign upon application of parity on the derivative operator? Then how do we give invariance given in the first line P : $A_{\mu}(\phi^{*}\partial_{\mu}\phi-\phi\partial_{\mu}\partial^{*})\rightarrow A_{\mu}(\phi^{*}\partial_{\mu}\phi-\phi\partial_{\mu}\phi^{*})$  when the vector fields $A_{\mu}$ transforms like a vector?
Or is it the book that is defining action of parity in a wrong way?

I found that similar question was given here

[How to perform parity tranformation in a Lagrangian?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/458429/)

but there was no satisfactory answer so I'm posting this again with clearer specification of the problem in seeking for help with these subtleties of parity transformation.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: How can the integral of a partiy invariant over all of space not be parity invariant? Jacobians are always positive.

Comment: @ConnorBehan  Seemingly yeah, the Lagrangian looks parity invariant, but note all fields appearing in it take on the values with respect to flipped position $(t,\vec{x})\rightarrow(t,-\vec{x})$ while the differential operator was unchanged upon parity operation since its additional sign canceled with those appearing from the 4-vector transformation of the vector current $\overline{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\psi$. I'm not sure then it would be good to say it is 'invariant in the action' which also flips the sign of the spatial part of the differential operator as well in the evaluation of the integral.